# how to compare to similar rows in two identical sql tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I have two identical tables as following:

Table 1

```
Student#|name|Course1#|Course2#|Course3#
456 abc 12  76  89
789 def 09  13  76
345 ghi 56  34  14
```

Table 2

```
Student#|name|Course1#|Course2#|Course3#
456 abc 12  76  89
789 def 90  13  76
345 ghi 56  34  14
```

Table1 will contain latest data and table 2 will keep a copy of table 1. Table 2 is updated everytime after updation of table 1 and I do not want a complete truncation and insertion. I want to fire a query which will compare these two tables and return only those rows in which value is changed. On the basis of these vale i can fire an update in table 2.

For eg: in table 1, student# 789 have a value changes for course 1# as 90 from 09, but table 2 still have old value. When I fire query i should get result like:

```
Student#|name|Course1#|Course2#|Course3#
789 def 90  13  76
```

Answer (score 0):

It would rarely make sense to have two copies of the same data let alone try to keep two copies of data and periodically try to keep them in sync.  So the premise seems rather suspect.

It sounds like you are looking for something like

```
UPDATE table2 t2
   SET (course1, course2, course3) = (SELECT course1, course2, course3
                                        FROM table1 t1
                                       WHERE t1.student = t2.student)
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM table1 t1
                WHERE t1.student = t2.student
                  AND (   t1.course1 != t2.course1
                       OR t1.course2 != t2.course2 
                       OR t1.course3 != t2.course3) );
```

This won't account for cases where either table has a `NULL` value.  If you want to replace a `NULL` value in `table2` with a non-NULL value from `table1` if it is available, and assuming -1 is not a valid value for that column, the predicate in the `EXISTS` clause would change to look something like `t1.course1 != nvl(t2.course1, -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create trigger on T1 for INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE ,in the trigger put the dirty KEYS/rows in onather table, then periodly check the dirty tracing table. Or in the trigger update T2 directlly.